# HOW to deploy C# application with GAC and NGEN

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, gac, ngen

I have small C# tool, compiled as Windows Application which goal is to wrap execution of other tools. This tool will be executed frequently, sometimes a 100 times a second and this is what I cannot change; same as this will work with Framework 2. Most important for this tool will be short warm startup.

Using Visual Studio 2013 I signed my assembly with strong name key. Compiled "Release" and got "EXE" file. Next I ran ngen /install app.exe

And this is all I could understand from a million posts here and out there.
Now I need to move this app.exe to my 12 servers and I have no idea if I should just ngen install on each machine, or should also copy my DEV windows/assembly folder structure to server windows/assembly (of course my application parts only).

I did ngen install on one server, but I don't see assembly created, so need help for more advanced heads.

Thanks 
Pawel.

UPDATE: I checked again and I found assembly in x64. So is it really enough to run ngen only?

RECAP: I copied exe to server did ngen install, checked that assembly is created. I run machine to launch exe 500 items - they all finished in 1 minute 24 seconds (from mutex log). I repeated test and got exactly the same result: 1.24 Next I did ngen uninstall and checked that assembly is deleted, it was. I run the same test and result was 1.26 (lol). Considering fact that it is stable and execution time is fully satisfactory for me I think I will give it up and stop researching to use GAC/NGEN. But any comments to this scenario and my original question are appreciated.

Comment: Starting a process a 100 times per second... I don't think that ngen is going to help a lot. I suggest a redesign. Think about a single instance (service maybe) spinning.

Comment: Sure, I would redesign, but it is the only way to run integration from the old and rusty system. I don't expect ngen to help a lot; if it can do a little it can be enough.

Comment: Most rusty old systems can create/write to a file. Have it do that. Monitor the file/folder with a single program.

Comment: `ngen` isn't guaranteed to help at all. In fact, it can cause worse performance in some cases. Measurement is the only thing that can help you. If you've only got a simple-as-nails console application with very little code, there's not going to be much of a slowdown on startup - the JIT compiler only compiles what it needs at the moment, so small apps get very little benefit from `ngen`. `ngen`ned code is not faster, it just avoids having to do some of the security checks and runtime compilation (but not all of it by far).

Comment: In the recap you mentioned 500 in 1 minute and 24 seconds, you were aiming for 100 per second... To me that is a huge difference and might affect the possible answers and comments considerably.

Comment: Erno, I wan't clear enough with my needs, sorry for that. The tool can be executed by a machine a 100 times at once or more. But it is not expected that it will do this every second, generally is no more than a million a week. I am looking for peak optimization. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should deploy all the assemblies your application needs to function to the new machine. Then you can NGEN if you want. An installer like WiX can do both for you. See [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/ngen_managed_assemblies.html).